# PopUp button showing on bottom Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, menu

i am making a popup menu on a fragment, the problem is when i show the popup menu that it shows on the bottom of the screen and I want it to show on the right high corner, does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance!!!!

[image: menu showing on the bottom]

Code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    binding.menuImageView.setOnClickListener(){
        showPopup(binding.root)
    }


    return binding.root
}

fun showPopup(v : View){
    val popup = PopupMenu(context, v)
    val inflater: MenuInflater = popup.menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, popup.menu)
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
        when(menuItem.itemId){
            R.id.about_menu-> {

            }
            R.id.signout_menu-> {

            }
        }
        true
    }
    popup.show()
}
```

I was trying to show the popup menu on the high right corner but it shows on the left bottom corner

Answer (score 0):

Solved, when you call the function showPopUp() you have to put the view where you want it to appear, in my case was showPopUp(binding.menuImageView)
Thanks.